# Least upper bound and greatest lower bound

Tags: real-analysis

Find the $\sup E$ and $\inf E$.

i) $E$=$(0,1]$

ii) $E$=$\{x \in Q : x^2 < 2\}$

i) $\sup E$ = $1$, $\inf E$ = $1$

ii)$\sup E$ = $\sqrt 2$, $\inf E$ = $DNE$

I got these answers using my intuition of sup and inf. Has it lead me astray?

Comment: Yes, you are led astray.  The inf is either the lowest number obtained, or if there is none, then the limit of a sequence which decreases as far as possible.  In part ii you have f(x) = $x^2$ on (-2,+2).  What is the biggest it can be?  And the smallest.  Are both those numbers attained or can you get there only in the limit?

Comment: I believe the sup is 4 and the inf is 0 then. 4 is by a limit and 0 is obtained. @BettyMock

Comment: Yes that is exactly right.  what about part i?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $i)$, $infE=0$ because it is the largest lower bound, every number in the set is greater than it but there is no number greater than 0 that is also a lower bound. The supremum is right though. Why do you say that the infimum does not exist for $ii$? What about $(-5)^2$?

Comment: For i) I agree.
For ii) the set is (-infinity, sqrt(2)) so therefore I thought it would not have a greatest lower bound since it is unbouded.

Comment: Why is the set $(-\infty,\sqrt{2})$? What happens to $-5$? Is $(-5)^2 < 2$?

Comment: I see. So the set is (√-2, √2)?

Comment: Try $(-\sqrt{2},\sqrt{2})$, $\sqrt{-2}\notin \mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: Yes, I need to work on my notation on here. Thank you.

Comment: @JeremyUpsal $-5^2$?  The condition is $x^2$ < 2.  We'll never get to -5.

Comment: Exactly. I am showing it is not in the set.